# setting EntitySet in SmartTable from view's controller

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, web-ide

I have two views, 
view A : Has a set of  entityset names, out of which one is chosen and passed to secondview; as a string.
view B : Has a smarttable that renders an entityset.

How to set the entityset in the smart table from the view's controller in View B? 
For example, if entityset called "aSet" is chosen in View A, then same is sent as argument to second view, View B. 
Then "aSet" should be set as entitySet in the smarttable in View B.

 The entity sets are listed in the metadata.

I am developing on SAP WebIDE, with views being written in xml and controller writter in js.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can. The entity set name property of the smart table control is not a dynamic UI5 property. You'll probably have to use another control to accomplish this, e.g. the responsive table.

Comment: what about calling to setEntitySet(vEntitySetName) and pass the entity set name. the setEntitySet exist under the smart table

Comment: Hassid sir, Thank you for the solution. I used the method, it gets set but I have to explicitly refresh the page, for the changes to take effect. Can you tell how I can overcome this (if its possible) ?

Answer (score 0):

you can bind your smart Table like this in controller:-

```
var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
var smartTable = this.getView().byId("tableId");

    smartTable.setEntitySet("entitySetName");
    smartTable.setInitiallyVisibleFields("columnsName");// can have one or many col
    smartTable.setModel(oModel);
```